# What could be the cause of strange brown discoloration around some bacterial strains' colonies on macconkey agar?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, morphology

**Acinetobacter**
[image]

**Unknown (Yellow TSI, Oxidase negative, Catalase positive)**
[image]

**Unseeded plate**
[image]

My only guess is that the initial pH of the poured agar is too acidic (too red), so any alkalinity is more marked. Could non-gram-negative contaminants with their normal unapparent growth on MacConkey agar, have an effect on the pH of the media?

I may have no way to check the pH of the liquid media prior to pouring and the presence of non-gram-negative contaminants.

So my only hope is that someone here is familiar with this scene and knows the reason behind it.